# Add Native ACF Fields with php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I know i can register ACF fields with php, in the way explained [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/),
Using `acf_add_local_field_group( $field_group )` and so.

But my question is, how can i register regular ACF fields, that would be available in the wp-admin ACF options and that i can manage from there later. using some one time php function.

My goal is:
I have a very long php array of names, and i need to make ACF fields by those names (actually each one has a key which i want to be used as the field's label and a value which i want to be used as the fields name). and i need those field to be manageable in the ACF admin area.

Is it possible some how? i can't find anything in the ACF documentation.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. That page on the ACF website that you supplied the link for is exactly the information you need. I think the code snippet under the sub-heading "Individual" would suit your needs, wrapping the `acf_add_local_field()` function with the `foreach` loop to process your array.

Comment: Hey @PeterHvD, Thanks, but this function will register the fields by the function, and if i remove the plugin / theme that the function is in the fields won't show in there post (they will stay on the database) and they will not be manageable in the ACF admin (for example if i want the client to be able to change there order or so he won't be able to (That's not the reason i need it, but just for the explanation).